# Как сделать сеточный фон в pygame | how to create cell background in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, разработка-игр, pygame

У меня есть проблема, как вы знаете когда мы ставим картинку в качестве фона в pygame она ставиться на определенные координаты, но как мне сделать чтобы эта картинка - [image: картинка] дублировала сама себя и выглядела примерно так [image: примерно так]

Comment: вы хотите чтобы у вас был шахматный бэкграунд?